# Заполнение одномерного списка (С++)

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, односвязный-список, linked-list

Каким образом можно заполнить одномерный список, если он состоит из 2-х страктур:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *pNext;
};

struct List
{
    Node *pFirst;
};
```

Вот то, что я попытался написать, но выдает ошибку
[Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
**tmp** было 0xCCCCCCCC., произошло ]:

```
void AddItems(List *Head, int item_quan)
{
    Node *q, *tmp;
    q = new Node;
    cout << "Enter value: ";
    cin >> q->value;
    q->pNext = NULL;

    if (!Head->pFirst)
        Head->pFirst = q;
    else
    {
        tmp = Head->pFirst;
        while (tmp->pNext) // (ОШИБКА!)
        {
            tmp = tmp->pNext;
        }
        tmp->pNext = q;
    }
}
```

Вот функция маин:

```
int main()
{
    List Head;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        AddItem(&Head, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Head->pFirst` не инициализирован, он не обязан быть `nullptr`, просто указывает куда-то. Ещё непонятно зачем в функции 2ой параметр, вы же его не используете. Пользуйтесь дебагером, это быстрее чем задавать вопросы из-за каждой мелочи)))))))

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ - помогло.
"дебагер" - это отладка ?

Comment: @ANGRYSHARKknyaz2000, да, дебагер это отладчик.